# onKeyUp is not working when activity losses focus

Tags: android, dialog

`onKeyUp()` is not working when activity losses focus. But at the same time `onBackPressed()` is working. I am displaying toast in these methods.

How can I use `onKeyUp()` if activity has not focus. 
Activity is losing focus due to an in app dialog.

Please help!

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " KEYCODE_MENU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentRea‌​ctContext()
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit("onKeyPressed", keyCode);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: show your code ?

Comment: Please check. Added it @Niceumang

Comment: your method is onkeyUp() ...right ? so what about onkeyDown() ??

Comment: oh. Same as onKeyUp. I am just replacing onKeyDown with onKeyUp in my question. @Niceumang

Comment: Activity's onKeyDown/onKeyUp methods not always called. Unlike them dispatchKeyEvent on Activity fired always. Move keydown/keyup logic here. Works well.

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // keydown logic
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: use 'event' instead of keycode like 'event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN.'

Comment: Not true. DispatchKeyEvent also not calling when activity has not focus. I have checked it. @Swati

Comment: @Niceumang. Don't you think it should display toast in either case?

Answer (score 0):

try with this one without dialog

```
   @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    Log.e("call","on key down");                   
                    return true;
          }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

if you are using dialog then in dialog use this

```
     DialogInterface.OnKeyListener keylistener = new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent KEvent) {
                    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();
                    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };


        final AlertDialog dialogs  = alert.create();
            dialogs.show();
            dialogs.setOnKeyListener(keylistener);
```

Comment: Still same issue. onKeyDown is not calling in case when there is any dialog.

Comment: ohh let me check with dialog

Comment: can you please tell me you are using default dialog or Fragment dialog?

Comment: yes please check. At the same time onBackPressed is calling.

Comment: Default dialog.

Comment: Let me explain all. I am capturing key event in MainActivity and passing it to javascript. As I am working on react-native. In my 1st react native, component these all event capturing code that is mentioned in my answer are working correctly. But in my 2nd component where there is a Youtube player from `react-native-youtube` library. These code are not working. 
So shortly I am not using a dialog like this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Avinash. :-)

Comment: i don't have knowledge about react native but this code is working fine for default dialog in android..